# R: averaging 15 min data to hourly for two columns of data in data frame

Tags: r

My data looks like this (with several other columns that I removed for simplicity.)

```
 Index   Date        Time Humid Temp    id
    93 4/3/16 12:00:00 AM  63.8 46.7 RSOSW
    94 4/3/16 12:15:00 AM  60.3 47.8 RSOSW
    95 4/3/16 12:30:00 AM  64.4 46.2 RSOSW
    96 4/3/16 12:45:00 AM  60.4 46.8 RSOSW
    97 4/3/16  1:00:00 AM  61.3 46.6 RSOSW
    98 4/3/16  1:15:00 AM  68.5 44.3 RSOSW
    99 4/3/16  1:30:00 AM  70.5 43.4 RSOSW
   100 4/3/16  1:45:00 AM  75.1 41.8 RSOSW
   101 4/3/16  2:00:00 AM  74.9 41.3 RSOSW
   102 4/3/16  2:15:00 AM  73.6 41.1 RSOSW
   103 4/3/16  2:30:00 AM  72.8 41.2 RSOSW
   104 4/3/16  2:45:00 AM  71.1 41.2 RSOSW
    93 4/3/16 12:00:00 AM  64.9 47.8 RSOSE
    94 4/3/16 12:15:00 AM  61.2 48.9 RSOSE
    95 4/3/16 12:30:00 AM  63.3 45.3 RSOSE
    96 4/3/16 12:45:00 AM  62.6 42.3 RSOSE
    97 4/3/16  1:00:00 AM  60.9 49.9 RSOSE
    98 4/3/16  1:15:00 AM  67.3 45.3 RSOSE
    99 4/3/16  1:30:00 AM  72.1 42.1 RSOSE
   100 4/3/16  1:45:00 AM  79.0 40.5 RSOSE
   101 4/3/16  2:00:00 AM  73.4 42.3 RSOSE
   102 4/3/16  2:15:00 AM  73.6 40.1 RSOSE
   103 4/3/16  2:30:00 AM  71.9 46.5 RSOSE
   104 4/3/16  2:45:00 AM  70.6 45.4 RSOSE
```

I would like to get the hourly mean Temp and Humidity by id. The result I am looking for is: (I would like to keep the other removed-for-simplicity columns of the data with each record.)

```
  Date  Hour  Humid   Temp    id
4/3/16    00 62.225 46.875 RSOSW
4/3/16    01  68.85 44.025 RSOSW
4/3/16    02   73.1   41.2 RSOSW
4/3/16    00     63 46.075 RSOSE
4/3/16    01 69.825  44.45 RSOSE
4/3/16    02 72.375 43.575 RSOSE
```

**Update**

```
  Index   Date        Time Humid Temp  serialnum       id         farm location
     93 4/3/16 12:00:00 AM  63.8 46.7 1310014696 RSOSW_16 River School  Outside
     94 4/3/16 12:15:00 AM  60.3 47.8 1310014696 RSOSW_16 River School  Outside
     95 4/3/16 12:30:00 AM  64.4 46.2 1310014696 RSOSW_16 River School  Outside
     96 4/3/16 12:45:00 AM  60.4 46.8 1310014696 RSOSW_16 River School  Outside
     97 4/3/16  1:00:00 AM  61.3 46.6 1310014696 RSOSW_16 River School  Outside
     98 4/3/16  1:15:00 AM  68.5 44.3 1310014696 RSOSW_16 River School  Outside
```

serialnum, id, farm and location are all characters.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(lubridate)
df[,2] <- mdy_hms(df[,2])

df %>% mutate(hour = hour(df[,2])) %>% 
  group_by(id, hour) %>% summarise_at(vars(Humid, Temp), mean)
```

Results are as follows

```
Source: local data frame [6 x 4]
Groups: id [?]

      id  hour  Humid   Temp
  <fctr> <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1  RSOSE     0 63.000 46.075
2  RSOSE     1 69.825 44.450
3  RSOSE     2 72.375 43.575
4  RSOSW     0 62.225 46.875
5  RSOSW     1 68.850 44.025
6  RSOSW     2 73.100 41.200
```

If you want to keep the columns as they are and replace the values with the means you calculated you can do

```
df %>% mutate(hour = hour(df[,2])) %>% 
  group_by(id, hour) %>% mutate_at(vars(Humid, Temp), mean) %>% head
```

And it will result in

```
Source: local data frame [6 x 6]
Groups: id, hour [2]

Index            datetime  Humid   Temp     id  hour
<int>              <time>  <dbl>  <dbl> <fctr> <int>
  1    93 2016-04-03 00:00:00 62.225 46.875  RSOSW     0
2    94 2016-04-03 00:15:00 62.225 46.875  RSOSW     0
3    95 2016-04-03 00:30:00 62.225 46.875  RSOSW     0
4    96 2016-04-03 00:45:00 62.225 46.875  RSOSW     0
5    97 2016-04-03 01:00:00 68.850 44.025  RSOSW     1
6    98 2016-04-03 01:15:00 68.850 44.025  RSOSW     1
```

#### Cleaning your Data (please post dput next time)

```
df <- read.table(text =
                 "93 4/3/16 12:00:00 AM  63.8 46.7 RSOSW
                 94 4/3/16 12:15:00 AM  60.3 47.8 RSOSW
                 95 4/3/16 12:30:00 AM  64.4 46.2 RSOSW
                 96 4/3/16 12:45:00 AM  60.4 46.8 RSOSW
                 97 4/3/16  1:00:00 AM  61.3 46.6 RSOSW
                 98 4/3/16  1:15:00 AM  68.5 44.3 RSOSW
                 99 4/3/16  1:30:00 AM  70.5 43.4 RSOSW
                 100 4/3/16  1:45:00 AM  75.1 41.8 RSOSW
                 101 4/3/16  2:00:00 AM  74.9 41.3 RSOSW
                 102 4/3/16  2:15:00 AM  73.6 41.1 RSOSW
                 103 4/3/16  2:30:00 AM  72.8 41.2 RSOSW
                 104 4/3/16  2:45:00 AM  71.1 41.2 RSOSW
                 93 4/3/16 12:00:00 AM  64.9 47.8 RSOSE
                 94 4/3/16 12:15:00 AM  61.2 48.9 RSOSE
                 95 4/3/16 12:30:00 AM  63.3 45.3 RSOSE
                 96 4/3/16 12:45:00 AM  62.6 42.3 RSOSE
                 97 4/3/16  1:00:00 AM  60.9 49.9 RSOSE
                 98 4/3/16  1:15:00 AM  67.3 45.3 RSOSE
                 99 4/3/16  1:30:00 AM  72.1 42.1 RSOSE
                 100 4/3/16  1:45:00 AM  79.0 40.5 RSOSE
                 101 4/3/16  2:00:00 AM  73.4 42.3 RSOSE
                 102 4/3/16  2:15:00 AM  73.6 40.1 RSOSE
                 103 4/3/16  2:30:00 AM  71.9 46.5 RSOSE
                 104 4/3/16  2:45:00 AM  70.6 45.4 RSOSE")

df[,2] <- paste(df[,2], df[,3], df[,4])
df <- df[,c(-3,-4)]

names(df) <- c("Index", "datetime", "Humid", "Temp", "id")
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on posting my data. I will do that next time. Is there a way to apply your code and keep the rest of the columns in the data frame? I have several columns after the ones I posted that I would like to keep with each record.

Comment: you can add columns to the end of a data frame using `mutate`, e.g., like we added the hour column. If you want to replace the values in several columns with their summaries, you can do that with `mutate_at`

Comment: Edited to reflect your latest question.

Comment: @phaser When you are reducing the number of rows (1 row per hour instead of 1 row per 15 minutes) R won't just assume that the other columns you want to keep are all the same. If you want to keep the `foo` column around you have two choices: (a) add `foo` to the grouping - in which case if there are multiple values of `foo` within one `id` and `hour` you will get a row for each value of `foo`, or...

Comment: (b) add `foo` to the `summarize` with a function that reduces the vector of `foo` values to a single value - `first(foo)` will take the first value - I like using `unique(foo)` because it will throw an error if more than one `foo` value is in the group. In this case, it would look like `summarise_at(vars(Humid, Temp, foo), funs(mean, mean, unique))`

Comment: @Gregor I assume this will work on characters? R is giving me an error with some of the columns that are characters.

Comment: Then maybe you have variation in your groups. I'm sure you can construct a toy example to test it - it will work on characters. It's hard to comment more without seeing the problematic data.

Comment: @Gregor Just figured out r is calculating a mean for every column and then unique for every column. Updating my post with more of my data.

Comment: So maybe the easiest solution for you is option (a) in my first comment - just add the other columns to the `group_by`.